# C# How do I know what methods need to be reimplemented for a class based on a interface that is to be used with a datagridview?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, datagridview, methods

I would like to make a class based on interfaces such as a list (or binding list) to store data that will be used with a datagridview

My question is when designing such code how can I easily find out what methods I need to implement to provide the required functionality and which interfaces need to be inherited (eg ICloneable, IComparible, IList, , IEnumerator, etc, etc)?

or another why of putting it, when inheriting a interface how can I easy find out which methods need to be custom written? does visual studio offer tools that help? obviously many methods will use generics and may not necessarily need rewriting.

Also how can I easily find out what methods (and there interfaces) a datagridview will call from its data source?

I have used a datagridview as an example, however, would be grateful of generic solutions that I can use in other areas in the future and learn from.

At the moment I am a bit overwhelmed when it comes to where to start and finding this information. Surely visual studio (express) has some functionality that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing for a DataGridView is to provide a correct DataSource. Have a look into the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

As written there, a DataSource must implement just one of the following interfaces:

- IList
- IListSource
- IBindingList
- IBindingListView

Using Visual Studio, as soon as you type

```
  public class MyClass : IBindingList
```

you will be offered a "smart tag", where Visual Studio suggests to make an empty implementation for all of your interface methods automatically.

Comment: Interfaces don't provide methods to be used "as is". You are intermixing this with default implementations of virtual functions in a base class.

Comment: Great this helps a lot thank you, is there a smart way to workout which methods don't need to be reimplemented and can be used as is? comment out and debug i suppose?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question...
If a class implements an interface, it must implement ALL members defined by the interface.

Comment: DataGridView.DataSource is of type "object" and can be initialised with different kind of things to make the DataGridView work.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I seem to be missing the relation to the question, please elaborate.

Comment: If I have a class which I want to use as a datasource, for example, how do I know what interfaces need to be used (inherited) and methods need to be reimplemented? Obviously, methods like Add (IList) would have to be reimplemented to handle the custom data structure within the new class. I would also have to find all the methods the datagridview calls and make sure the class handles them correctly.

Comment: Simply have a look here in the "Remarks" section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Comment: @Daniel: .. since "DataGridView.DataSource" takes an object, you can assign almost anything to it, the compiler does not tell you which interfaces you have to implement. However, you will get a runtime error. The obvious thing here to do for the OP is to HAVE A LOOK INTO THE DOCS, RTFM!!!

Comment: @Doc Brown: Yeah, that's where I pointed him in my last comment ;)

Comment: @Daniel: me too, posted the same link almost simultanously :-)

Comment: @Doc Brown: At least, now he knows, that it's the right one ;-)

Comment: @Doc Brown @Daniel remarks section is of great help thank you I hadn't noticed this key information having not developed with C# for long.

Comment: @Doc Brown sometimes reading the manual isnt good enough you can be overwhelmed with information and go round in circles. Everyone needs some pointers now and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .net Reflector to view the microsoft control asemblies. It will show you all base classes and interfaces controls implement. Failing that MSDN usually has good documentation on all its controls.

DataGridView details can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx